# file.create syntax

Tags: r

Super big newbie to R. I'm a bit stuck on the file.create function. I've used it successfully to create a file in the set working directory and also when I've already created a separate file path and assigned that file path to a variable.

However, why can't I use file.create and simply list the desired file path and file name without the file.path function? Does the `file.create` function not possess the capacity to automatically create the file in the specified directory, but requires the `file.path` function to secure the path to the directory?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. I do apologize if this question is rather elementary but I'd like to get the fundamentals down.

Here's the code that worked:

```
BasicDir <- "/Users/slam1924/Desktop/LearnR Tutorials"
setwd(BasicDir)
file.create("myfile.doc")
fp1 <- file.path("/Users/slam1924/Desktop/Vocal Covers", "mytext.doc")
fp1
file.create(fp1)
```

Alternative:

```
file.create(file.path("/Users/slam1924/Desktop/Vocal Covers", "mytext.doc"))
```

Here's the code that failed:

```
file.create("/Users/slam1924/Desktop/Vocal Covers", "mytext.doc")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by reading the help for the function. `help(file.create)`. The usage is `file.create(..., showWarnings = TRUE)`

Under Details you'll see

> file.create creates files with the given names if they do not already
>   exist and truncates them if they do.

So when you try

```
file.create("/Users/slam1924/Desktop/Vocal Covers", "mytext.doc")
```

It's trying to create two files, one of which ("/Users/slam1924/Desktop/Vocal Covers") is likely already a directory.

If the file or directory already exists, you'll see an error like:

```
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In file.create("data") :
  cannot create file 'data', reason 'Permission denied'
```

You could fix this by sending the function one string. Change your code that failed to:

`file.create("/Users/slam1924/Desktop/Vocal Covers/mytext.doc")`

Comment: Super. Thank you so much! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: I get an error when I try this: cannot create file...reason 'No such file or directory'. The directory exists but the file doesn't (which is why I'm trying to create it), but it works if I use `setwd()` beforehand and then only cite the file name when creating the file: `file.create("mytext.doc")`. I'd prefer not having to use `setwd()`.